# GWT Anchor action by hand

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, anchor, uibinder

I have an Anchor widget in my gwt-application.
If you click on it a link will bring you to a website.

I want to call the link by hand in a program-method.
Like: anchor.click()  ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Window.Location.assign(anchor.getHref());
```

should work.